# Get Image or byte data with http

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-http

For a web application I need to get my images with an ajax request because we have signature + authentication on our API, so we can't get images using a simple `<img src="myapi/example/145"/>`

Since we're using angular2, we obviously looked for blob or something like that, but as stated in `static_response.d.ts` file:

```
/**
 * Not yet implemented
 */
blob(): any;
```

So okay, I can't do it for now, I have to wait for thie feature to be implemented.

But problem is I can't wait so I need a hotfix or a little hack to be able to get image data from response and I'll be able to remove my hack and set the `blob()` method call to be good when it will be implemented.

I tried this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private api:ApiService, private logger:Logger){}
    title = 'Tests api';
    src='http://placekitten.com/500/200'; //this is src attribute of my test image
    onClick(){ //Called when I click on "test" button
        this.api.test().then(res => {
            console.log(res._body);
            var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(res._body)],{
                type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
            });
            var urlCreator = window.URL;
            this.src = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
        });
    }
}
```

with `ApiService.test()` method:

```
test():Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get(this._baseUrl + "myapi/example/145", this.getOptions())
//getOptions() is just creating three custom headers for     
//authentication and CSRF protection using signature
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                    this.logger.debug(res);
                if(res.headers.get("Content-Type").startsWith("image/")){
                    return res;
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(res => {
                this.logger.error(res);
                return res.json();
            } );
    }
```

But I don't get any image from it and logging the response data shows a big string which is image data.

Do you have a hack to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is not necessary to extend `BrowserXhr` anymore. (Tested with angular 2.2.1) 
[RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html#!#responseType-anchor) now has a property `responseType: ResponseContentType` which can be set to `ResponseContentType.Blob`

Using DomSanitizer

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

This example also creates a sanitized url that can be bound to the `src` property of an `<img>`

```
this.http.get(url,  {
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'},
                        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
                    })
        .map(res => {
            return new Blob([res._body], {
                type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
            });
        })
        .map(blob => {
            var urlCreator = window.URL;
            return  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
        })
```

Comment: Today you can use `res => res.blob()`.

Comment: In newer versions of Angular use
`headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')`

Answer (score 12):

Using the new Angular HttpClient is really easy to achieve this. Going off of tschuege's approach, it would be:

```
return this._http.get('/api/images/' + _id, {responseType: 'blob'}).map(blob => {
  var urlCreator = window.URL;
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
})
```

The key is to set the responseType as 'blob' so that it doesn't attempt to parse it as JSON

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think that you missed to set the `responseType` on your request. Right now it's a bit tricky because it's not supported.

The workaround would be to override the `BrowserXhr` class to set the `responseType` on the `xhr` object itself...

You could extend the `BrowserXhr`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended class:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

The problem is here that you don't override for all requests. At the bootstrap level, it will override everything. So you could provide it in a sub injector within the `providers` attribute of the impacted component...

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/tC8xD16zwZ1UoEojebkm?p=preview.

Comment: So I would have two http providers, one for byte requests and one for json ones?

Comment: Yes, the default one for requests that return json and the custom one for ones that return binary...

Comment: I dded a plunkr link in my answer

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Hey this plunker is no longer working. Can you update it or update the code here? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This JSFiddle could help you:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/yy7Zs/936/

The method is, as you wanted, creating a Blob from the URL provided

```
// Image returned should be an ArrayBuffer.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open( "GET", "https://placekitten.com/500/200", true );

// Ask for the result as an ArrayBuffer.
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    // Obtain a blob: URL for the image data.
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Problem is that this is a full JS solution, I need a TS hack which can be achieved with Response object to be easy to remove when blob() function will be available.