# Download file with angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to download file from server. it may be `.pdf, .xslx, .docx` etc. I have this code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile(int Id)
    {
        var file = Uow.Files.GetSingleById(Id);

        if (file == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File not found");
        }

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        var stream = new FileStream(String.Concat(RepositoryPath.Root, file.PhysicalPath), FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

and if I click to download response is this:
[image]

and in angular2:

```
downloadFile(id: number) {
        this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/DownloadFile/' + id).subscribe();
}
```

in httpcall service:

```
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Language': this.ls.actLan });

get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + url, { headers: this.headers })
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.log('error');
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

and in web.config I have cors enabled

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

When I click to download button it says:

> Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0

What's wrong?

Comment: What line of code does cause this error? What is this code supposed to do?
 `this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/DownloadFile/' + id).subscribe();`

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is **not** JSON, therefore I wouldn't expect `let body = res.json();` in `extractData` to do something meaningful.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it should get file from server and return to the client browser. anyway I hope this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152917/get-image-or-byte-data-with-http might help

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you provide me any further details? can't solve by that answer

Comment: Why can't you solve with that answer?