# Angular - Display byte array as image

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api that returns a byte[], i want to display it as an image in my front application, so i used data url to display the image

```
this.cardBackgroundService.getImage(event.data.entitlementCertificateNumber, "C003").subscribe(data => {
  this.image = data;
  console.log(this.image);
});

<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}"/>
```

the problem is when i display the response of the api in the console, it has this format and it doesn't display as an image

> �PNG 
>   �Ou���j�000000000H��a````````` ��a````````��a `````````��a```````` ��a```````��a ````````��a````````` ��a````````��a `````````��a```````` ��a```````��a ````````��a````````�.r�*��*��X��V��QS��\�ۂ���F�`�{lhXnJU��s��iiǯ�O1�;������

Comment: try `this.image = btoa(data);`

Comment: i have this error: `Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Comment: otherwise this 'might' work: `<img src="data:image/png,{{image}}"/>`, so just remove the base64

Comment: Refer this link :- <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152917/get-image-or-byte-data-with-http>

Comment: what is the typescript service type for byte?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467236/react-typescript-api-type-for-java-byte-image-png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert your image data to a dataURL:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => this.image = e.target.result;
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([data]));
```

And in your component:

```
<img [src]="image"/>
```

Make sure you set the `responseType` to be of type `'blob'` in your `getImage()` http [get](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) request.

Comment: So what type of image from AWS should I set in my Spring Boot image field? byte[]? I want to send from backend to the frontend ResponseObject with some fields and also with image field...

Comment: what is the typescript service type for byte?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467236/react-typescript-api-type-for-java-byte-image-png

Answer (score 12):

You can display like this, it worked with me.

Import `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Add `DomSanitizer` to `constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }`

```
this.cardBackgroundService.getImage(event.data.entitlementCertificateNumber, "C003")
.subscribe(data => {

  let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
  this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
});
```

In HTML

```
<img [src]='image' />
```

Comment: i have this error: `data:image/png;base64,%EF%BF%BDPNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%034%00%00%01%EF%BF%BD%08%02%00%00%00r@%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%00%00%EF%BF%BD%00IDATx%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%05XU%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD?%EF%BF%BDw%EF%BF%BD%1B%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDw%EF%BF%BDV@%11%0B%0B%EF%BF%BD.% net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

Comment: you need check your image content, you can see the demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-image-from-api

Comment: what is the typescript service type for byte?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467236/react-typescript-api-type-for-java-byte-image-png

Comment: This is Perfect example, @HienNguyen , thanx for your vital post on stackblitz :) Happy to fix on my side, some folks were mention to append URL, dont know how it works t=in there case, but for me it is huge headache of ALB from AWS, but this way great working for me. thnx again.

Comment: @HienNguyen I need to know whats wrong here, can you please help me here as well ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912311/how-to-render-image-from-backend-server-as-byte-array-to-html-div-style-backgrou